# Law of large numbers with incomplete observation

Tags: probability, statistics, law-of-large-numbers

I am currently reading the book *Introduction to Reinforcement Learning* by R. S. Sutton and A. G. Barto.
The authors often reason with the LLN. In particular, at one point there is an expression like this (beginning of Section 2.2 - Action-value Methods)
$$
 \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{t-1}R_i \mathbb{1}_{\{A_i = a\}}}{\sum_{i=1}^{t-1} \mathbb{1}_{\{A_i = a\}}},
 $$
where $R_i$ are the rewards and $A_i$ are the actions taken at time $i$. If I understand correctly, they claim that by the LLN, this expression converges to the mean of $R_i$ as long as Action $a$ is chosen infinitely often. Intuitively this of course makes sense, but I am not convinced.
I am familiar with the LLN like this:
Take $X_1,X_2,\dots$ iid, where $\mathbb{E}[|X_1|]$ exists. Then
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i = \mathbb{E}[X_1] \hspace{20pt}
 $$
almost surely. I tried to recreate the situation from the book like this:
We have two sequences $X_1,X_2,\dots$ iid and $C_1,C_2,\dots$ iid (if necessary, let the two sequences be independent), where $\mathbb{E}[|X_1|]$ and $\mathbb{E}[|C_1|]$ exist. Let $\mathbb{P}[C_i = \pm 1] = 1/2$. Then intuitively the expression
$$
 \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}X_i \mathbb{1}_{\{C_i = 1\}}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{1}_{\{C_i = 1\}}}
 $$
should indeed converge almost surely to $\mathbb{E}[X_1]$, since the probability of $\{C_i = 1\}$ only finitly many times is zero (i.e. you observe $X_i$ infinitely often almost surely).

If this is correct, how can you argue this rigorously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For general case, you can try Toeplitz lemma:

> **Toeplitz Lemma.**
> Suppose that $x_{n}\to x$ and for $a_{i}\geq0$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, then
> $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}x_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}}\to x.$$

Under your recreated situation, say $X_{i}$ and $C_{i}$ are independent, the proof becomes much easier. By LLN, with probability 1, you have
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}1_{\{C_{i}=c\}}\to\mathbb{E}[X_{i}1_{\{C_{i}=c\}}]=\mathbb{E}[X_{i}]\mathbb{E}[1_{\{C_{i}=c\}}],$$
in the meantime, with probability 1,
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}1_{\{C_{i}=c\}}\to\mathbb{E}[1_{\{C_{i}=c\}}].$$
Since $\mathbb{E}[1_{\{C_{i}=c\}}]=\mathbb{P}(C_{i}=c)$ must be nonzero
by Borel–Cantelli lemma, a simple divide yields desired result.

Comment: This "Toeplitz lemma" is the same as that proven in Loève, M. 1977. Probability Theory I, correct?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes. I just checked that book, the Toeplitz lemma in that book is more general.